# Choosing Rows in a Case Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `a` below

```
YEAR_WW
2016-23
2016-24
2016-25
2016-26
2016-27
2016-28
2016-29
2016-30
2016-31
2016-32
2016-33
2016-34
2016-35
```

And I have a case statement that pulls the data from that table to another table defined.

```
SELECT Family,Value,YEAR_WW
            ,weekly_qty = CASE WHEN YEAR_WW = '2016-23' THEN week1
                            WHEN YEAR_WW = '2016-24' THEN week2
                            WHEN YEAR_WW = '2016-25' THEN week3
                            WHEN YEAR_WW = '2016-26' THEN week4
                            WHEN YEAR_WW = '2016-27' THEN week5
                            WHEN YEAR_WW = '2016-28' THEN week6
                            WHEN YEAR_WW = '2016-29' THEN week7
                            WHEN YEAR_WW = '2016-30' THEN week8
                            WHEN YEAR_WW = '2016-31' THEN week9
                            WHEN YEAR_WW = '2016-32' THEN week10
                            WHEN YEAR_WW = '2016-33' THEN week11
                            WHEN YEAR_WW = '2016-34' THEN week12
                            ELSE week13 END
FROM sample_table
```

Instead of hard coding the values from table `a` in the case statement, is there a way to specify the row numbers on the case statement?  i.e:

```
WHEN YEAR_WW = [first_row] THEN week1
WHEN YEAR_WW = [second row] THEN week2...
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL?  The code does not look like MySQL.  Also, what are `week1`, `week2`, and so on.  Are these columns?

Comment: I don't think there's something like what you asked for. You could though, in a somewhat hacky way, take the substring after the dash, cast it to integer and subtract 22 from it to obtain the week number as you describe.

Comment: What do you mean writing first_row? If you will not specify data from the YEAR_WW in query  you can insert any week* in the result.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff yes, week1 and week2 afer coloumns. I am using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: @AstraSerg I am just writing it as an example. I want the first case to choose the first row from table a and the second case to choose the second row from table a and so on...

Comment: @rgoliveira the problem the data might change, I just want to specify the rows instead of the actual values in the row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your sample tables correctly;

I think you could use ROW_NUMBER()

```
SELECT Family, Value, YEAR_WW
    , CONCAT('week', ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR, i),13))
FROM sample_table X
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY YEAR_WW) AS i, YEAR_WW
            FROM a
            ) Y
ON X.weekly_qty = Y.YEAR_WW
```

And to be safe with the ordering, you might want to use `ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, LEFT(YEAR_WW,4)*52)+CONVERT(INT, RIGHT(YEAR_WW,2))`
instead of just `ORDER BY YEAR_WW`